# I can not find my objects folder or I don't have a name for it in swift?

Tags: xcode

[It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmLKF.png) <<< screenshot from other xcode image online

I can't find my layers tab like the list of objects in swift. Can anybody help?

I tried looking for it in the view tab but I don't know what to do call it

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "layers tab" and "list of objects"? You mean the objects you see in the debugger (the "view debugger" and/or the "memory graph")?

Comment: I clarified that I don't know what to call it. If you could give me the name of the tab bar and to make it appear that will be great, thanks

Comment: I just want sidebar that is shown in the image to appear that is all.

Answer (score 0):

There is a button "Show/Hide Document Outline" as @Rob said on the comment. The marked button in the bellow screen shot.
[image]